# Ebean model based on a OneToOne field

Tags: playframework, ebean

If I have a model which contains a OneToOne relationship:

```
class Person {
  int id;
  String name;
  int age;
  Detail detail;
}

class Detail {
  int id;
  String description
}
```

If I have the `id` of `Detail`, how to get the `Person` based on the `Detail` ID?

In `django`, I can do something like `Person.objects.filter(detail__id = id_of_detail)[0]`

Comment: See if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/18500581/1205368